# how to send .apk file using social media platforms after building it in android studio

Tags: android, build, apk, build.gradle

I am trying to build file .apk file of my app and than send to someone on whatsapp so that he can check it out and this way is working perfectly fine before but now I am sending this .apk file to my friend it is not going as an .apk file. When he is trying to opening it is asking for extracting or copying it somewhere else. Can anyone tell me how I can send my .apk file to someone else using any social media platform or anything else.I am adding screenshots here please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObnVU.jpg)

Comment: change the file format from .apk to .pdf and sent it. at receiver end again change the format from .pdf to .apk that it.

Comment: but then I am not he is not able to install it on his mobile I am able to send it but it is not going as an .apk file means when he is trying to opening it it is not installing it is giving option to extract or see the file

Comment: because he is installing the APK by whatsApp chat click, try to find the path of that APK and go to that path in file explorer and from there try to install it.

Comment: anyway thanks for your time renaming it worked for me

Comment: enjoy  your way :)

Answer (score 0):

Both you and your friend can use [Es File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) for this. Then follow the steps provided in the link below.

> [How to send, receive and install apps via WhatsApp on your Android device](https://www.techzim.co.zw/2016/12/send-receive-install-apps-via-whatsapp-android-device/)

I hope this will solve your problem and help you.

Comment: I am able to send but then my friend is not able to install it it is giving option to see it and extract it but not giving option to install it

Comment: @RohitBhamu I can not see the photos you please tell me what happened. Your friend can't install your.apk file on his phone?

Comment: yeah I send him the .apk file but he is not able to install it . it is behaving like. a .zip file

Answer (score 0):

Go to file explorer  , and try installing  YOUR_APP.apk  from WhatsApp/Media/whatsapp_documents.  Hope it works